# Upload PDF as binary data to SQL Server via NEXT.js app

Tags: pdf, next.js, varbinary

I am trying to solve this problem:

I am building an app in NEXT.js where users should upload certain documents (pdf,docx,etc.). I need to store those documents inside SQL Server as blobs. I do not know how should I pass data content of selected file to the API. I tried to use arrayBuffer or convert it to text and then cast as varbinary but without any success. I probably need completely different approach on this but was not able to find anything useful to my particular situation.
Thanks in advance!

```js
async function filesUpload(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const file = e.target.file.files[0];
  

  /** File validation */
  if (!file.type.startsWith("application/pdf")) {
    alert("Please select a valid document");
    return;
  }
  const buffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
  console.log(buffer)
  console.log({DATA: await file.text()})

  const endpoint = '/api/PostData/insertContractDoc';
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({DATA: await file.text()}),
    }

    //const response = await (await fetch(endpoint, options)).json()
  
  return
}
```

And this is my API endpoint:

```js
const sql = require('mssql');
const configOBJ = require('../../../components/configSQL.js');

export default async function getAll(req,res){
    await sql.connect(configOBJ.confSQL).then(pool => { 
        console.log("insert into [CONTRACTDOCUMENTS] values(302,1,null,null,'adad',CAST("+ req.body.DATA+" AS VARBINARY(MAX)))")
        let querySTR = "insert into [CONTRACTDOCUMENTS] values(302,1,null,null,'adad',CAST("+ req.body.DATA+" AS VARBINARY(MAX)))"
        return pool.request().query(querySTR)
    }).then(result => {

        //console.log(result);
        return res.status(200).json(result);
    }).catch(err => {
        // ... error checks
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).send(err);
    })
}
```

Comment: I've untagged SQL Server - you are not looking for an SQL Server expert, you need a next.js expert who can tell you how to get the data to SQL Server. In other programming languages you use parameters to pass data to your SQL Query, which is then trivial to pass varbinary data. I'd be surprised if you can pass it using string concatenation as you are attempting.

Comment: Yes that's what I am exactly thinking. I am nextjs newbie so my approach is very unlikely the right one.